# Storing Logs in Azure function

Tags: azure, logging

I want store all the log that i put in application like,
What was input request and also what was output object.
Some interm states of about objects and about logic and  output response in JSON and store

```
 log.LogInformation("Final list of objects is" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalSelectedItems));
```

Actually I want see latter on What was input request, what was different states of different objects and output result as I want this for debugging.

The system is dynamic and I can't replicate the scenarios when system doesn't behave as anticipated, So want see all information when system is not behaving properly

Comment: what is the question here? you just need to store whatever info you have

Comment: Did you integrate your Azure Function App with Application Insights?

Comment: Yes want store logs persistently

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes dear